# Evaluate $ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2+ab}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $ \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2+ab}\:\mathrm{d}x$, where $0<a<b$.

Nothing meaningful came to my mind.

Comment: i think for such a integral exists no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: that is false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is useful to exploit a symmetry. If we replace $x$ with $\frac{ab}{x}$ we get:
$$ I = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\log x}{x^2+ab}\,dx = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\log(ab)-\log(x)}{x^2+ab}\,dx $$
hence:
$$ 2\, I = \log(ab)\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x^2+ab} = \frac{\log(ab)}{\sqrt{ab}}\left(\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}-\arctan\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)$$
and
$$\boxed{ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\log x}{x^2+ab}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\log(ab)}{2\sqrt{ab}}\,\arctan\left(\frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{ab}}\right)}.}$$

Comment: whenever I see the question on integral, I am waiting for your answer,+1)